# Поэзия не профессия, поэзия как любовь: если уж есть, так есть она, а нет - и не суесловь

Tags: тире, синтаксический-разбор

> Поэзия не профессия, поэзия как любовь: если уж есть, так есть она, а нет — и не суесловь.

Помогите, пожалуйста, определить главные чл. предл., и объяснить почему стоит тире.

Answer (score 1):

**Поэзия**(подлеж.) **не профессия**(сказ.), **поэзия**(подлеж.) **как любовь**(сказ.): если уж **есть**(сказ.), так **есть**(сказ.) **она**(подлеж.), а **нет**(сказ.) - и **не суесловь**(сказ.)

... а нет - и не суесловь.- тире вместо запятой в СПП, если придаточное стоит перед главным, для большего подчёркивания (если есть любовь,так она есть, а если её нет, то и не надо говорить лишний раз). Частица "И" вместо "то и".